# Weaker condition for the excision axiom

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

This comes from a question I asked on mathstackexchange (link: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740937/weaker-condition-for-the-excision-axiom?noredirect=1#comment10054797_4740937))

The excision axiom in homology states that if $\overline Z\subseteq\operatorname{Int}A$, then $h_n(X\setminus Z,A\setminus Z)$ is isomorphic to $h_n(X,A)$, where the map is induced by the inclusion.

What I want to ask is the following. Suppose I can prove the isomorphism for the special case that $Z$ is closed with $Z\subseteq A$ (or $Z\subseteq\operatorname{Int}A$, whichever works), would it imply the excision axiom

Comment: Welcome! Please add a link to your stackexchange question.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Just added the link :)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific: what class of objects are $(X,A)$ and $Z$, and also what do you mean by "homology"?  Your notation makes this look a little like an Eilenberg-Steenrod axiom homework problem.

Comment: @RyanBudney Sure. I want $(X,A)$ to be any pair of spaces, with $A\subseteq X$. But if restricting to CW complexes works better, that's also great. By "homology" I mean the one defined by Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. What I wonder is the following: suppose I have functors $h_n$, and I checked all the axioms except excision; now I prove excision under the assumption that $Z$ is closed, would that imply the usual excision?